# Angular BehaviorSubject onSubscribe event / Lazy loading api data

Tags: angular, hateoas, behaviorsubject

I'm trying to implement lazy loading of HATEOAS api data in Angular 5. Let's assume I have a class `Car` which holds a reference to an instance of `Engine`, but the engine should only be loaded if it gets accessed.

A class `Car`:

```
export class Car {
    private _engine = new BehaviorSubject<Engine>(null);
    engine = _engine.asObservable()

    constructor(
        private enginesService
    ) {}
}
```

A class `Engine`:

```
export class Engine {
    type: string;
}
```

Some template with access to an instance of `Car` via a component variable `car`, which asynchronously accesses the engine observable:

```
<div *ngIf="car.engine | async; let engine; else loadingEngine">
    <p>{{engine.type}}</p>
</div>
<ng-template #loadingEngine>Loading engine...</ng-template>
```

Above, the car does not know when `engine` is accessed and does not know that the engine must be loaded from the api. Now I tried to offer access to Car.engine only via a getter method, which would return `car.asObservable()` and trigger the api request, like so:

```
export class Car {
    private _engine = new BehaviorSubject<Engine>(null);

    constructor(
        private enginesService
    ) {}

    engine(): Observable<Engine> {
        this.enginesService.getEngine().subscribe( engine => {
            _engine.next(engine);
        )
        return _engine.asObservable()
    }
}
```

But when using the method in the template it was called over and over again, causing many api requests, crashing the browser.

I had the idea of wrapping the `BehaviorSubject` in a class which offers an `onSubscribe` event. The `Car` could subscribe the `onSubscribe` event and would know when something is trying to get the engine value. Is there any other way of knowing when `engine` is accessed?

**Edit:**

[funkizer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8327383/funkizer) brought me to cold observables. I updated my `Car` implementation to offer the engine as a cold observable. Now the car does not even need to know if the engine gets accessed, it just offers the observable once and each subscriptions triggers the api call:

```
export class Car {
    private _engine: Engine;
    engine: Observable<Engine> = new Observable( observer => {
        enginesService.getEngine().subscribe( engine => {
            this._engine = engine;
            observer.next(this._engine);
        }
    })

    constructor(
        private enginesService
    ) {}
}
```

Comment: Can you put the implementation of `enginesService`?

Comment: every time you are calling engine() your subscribing to a new observable .. thats what is causing your browser crash

Comment: you need to change the implementation of your component

Comment: @Ricardo Thanks for pointing that out, I didn't notice I was instantiating a new observable every time the `enging()` method was called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HttpClient returns cold observables (will only do anything when someone subscribes), so you don't need to subscribe to the api call in Car, and the api call will only happen when needed. You can just pass the Observable to the template through `shareReplay()` so there'll only be one api request. Try:

```
engine$:Observable<Engine> = this.enginesService.getEngine().pipe(shareReplay(1))

<div *ngIf="car.engine$|async as engine">...
```

**Edit:** Full StackBlitz example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ea52a7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: "Hot and cold observables" was the key here. I could not just pass through the observable from the HttpClient because the service first handles the result, checks the status code, handles the JSON, etc. But I changed my `Car` implementation to have a cold engine observable. I updated the question.

Comment: Why not do all that processing in map() ? It doesn't make an observable hot.

Comment: From how I understand your comment, you would implement map inside `Car` to handle the response from the `HttpCient`. But `Car` should not have to worry about how to deal with engine api calls, deal with errors, etc.. For loose coupling and strong cohesion it should only handle car-stuff and leave everything related to `Engine` to the `EngineService`. Else I would have to reimplement the map() in every class that uses `Engine`.

Comment: Yeah no mapping in Car, always map in the service, so consumers get an observable of ready-to-use data (and it's still a cold one) :)

Comment: See stackblitz of how I'd do it. Follow the console, you can see how shareReplay caches the engines even if you close/open the hoods multiple times: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ea52a7?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Also note the absence of subscribe calls. Whenever you're calling subscribe in a component or service, it's usually time to think if there's a better way to organize logic.